# fbml not getting parsed/rendered on ajax response

Tags: facebook, fbml

I am developing a facebook app (using iframe).

I have a situation where my page is fully loaded and it shows the fbml content (request-form) properly, but then on some action, I make ajax call to fetch updated fbml content from server (php). It brings the code, but that **fbml is not getting parsed/rendered**, and the enclosing div remains blank.

Following is the fbml that i am fetching using ajax:

```
<fb:serverfbml width="615">
        <script type="text/fbml">
            <fb:fbml>   
                <fb:request-form action="some value"
                                 .......//other code.....>
                        <fb:multi-friend-selector                               
                                .......//other code.....
                                />
                </fb:request-form>
            </fbml>
        </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

After **ajax response**, the enclosing div remains blank, but in firebug i could see following code in it:

```
<div id="enclosing_div_id">
<fb:serverfbml width="615"> </fb:serverfbml>
    <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:fbml>   
            <fb:request-form action="some value"
                             .......//other code.....>
                    <fb:multi-friend-selector                               
                            .......//other code.....
                                 />
            </fb:request-form>
        </fbml>
    </script>
</div>
```

Though, it's not getting rendered on my page.

Please guide.

Thanks

==============================

UPDATE:

I have checked all of following, but they don't seem to be working in my case.

```
FB.XFBML.parse();

if ( FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree )
    setTimeout( FB.XFBML.Host.parseDomTree, 0 );


FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('invite_new_div'), function() {
 alert('I rendered');
});
```

Please note I've not used FBJS in my app so far.

Comment: Did you try to execute that FB parse code and the alert didn't pop-up? If yes, are you using the correct div id? The first html example is using id="enclosing_div_id" but the FB parse is looking for an element with id of 'invite_new_div'.

Comment: yes, the alert pops up, but the div remains blank. And yes, the div id is correct; in earlier code, i just used example.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just putting the fbml code into your div and not pulling in the output content which should have been rendered on the facebook server and presented to you as standard html. The browser doesn't know how to render fbml so that is why you just see an empty div.

Update: After you have posted the FB js code it makes sense. According to this artice:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

You can only render the following fbml tags:

```
* fb:activity
* fb:add-profile-tab
* fb:bookmark
* fb:comments
* fb:friendpile
* fb:like
* fb:like-box
* fb:live-stream
* fb:login-button
* fb:recommendations
* fb:serverFbml
* fb:profile-pic
* fb:user-status
```

As you can see the form element is not listed as one of them. This might be your problem.

Comment: I understand that, but when the page loads, it perfectly parses and renders the same fbml code that I have mentioned here (the one i am getting from ajax response). I believe it's because the facebook parses the fbml on page load, but the question is, how to make it parse and render the fbml dynamically on ajax response, some time after the page is fully loaded?

Comment: Right, because your app is either parsing the fbml and spitting out html or the fbml is parsed by the facebook servers and spit back out as html for you when you're loading the page in the iframe. Please provide us with more information and I will try to help you troubleshoot this further.

Comment: @ DeviantSeev : facebook documentation (above link) says fb:serverfbml can be rendered. But i am not sure whether fb:request-form inside it could be rendered or not. That's where i m stuck. Anyway thanks for all the help so far..

Comment: @Prashant - In the original code that you pasted, your form is actually not within the serverfblm tags but outside of it. Also, serverFbml uses a capital 'F' in Fbml - Not sure if it's case sensitive?

Comment: the request-form is automatically getting placed outside serverFbml  tags when I assign the ajax response to div. not sure how.